# Operand type clash: text is incompatible with datetime PDO Error

Tags: php, sql, pdo, odbc

So i have this php insert script using pdo.

```
$i = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO MEMB_INFO (memb___id, memb__pwd, memb_name, sno__numb,bloc_code, ctl1_code,mail_chek, mail_addr,modi_days) VALUES (?, [dbo].[fn_md5](?,?),?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$i->execute(array($username,$password,$username,'test','111111111111','0','0','1',$email,'2005-01-03'));
```

But whenever i run it show me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash:
>   text is incompatible with datetime (SQLExecute[206] at
>   ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)'

modi_days is datetime type with 8 length

Comment: It seems your are trying to convert date to time (or to datetime?): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx Let us know `modi_days` type. What means 8 length ?

Comment: modi_days type is datetime with length 8

Comment: You specify 9 columns but the execute has 10 values.  I'm not familiar with that VALUES syntax but it looks as though you are at least missing a comma.  Also, your date string is more than 8 characters.

Comment: @danihp: I see now the function params.

Comment: Depending on your server's date settings SQL-Server will not recognize `2005-01-03` as a date (because with `DATEFORMAT DMY` this is the 3rd Jan, with `DATEFORMAT MDY` this is 1st March), use yyyyMMdd. This is culture independent.

Comment: @GarethD same error....

Comment: @have you tried to execute this insert directly to MSSQL Server through Management Studio?

Comment: Have you tried to cast to date before post: `...'0','0','1',$email, strtotime('2005-01-03')));`

Comment: @danihp yes, when i put 2005-01-03 it makes it 1/3/2005.
If i use 1/3/2005 on insert, same error

Comment: @danihp with strtotime('2005-01-03') i got same error

Comment: If i use this in query:
INSERT INTO MEMB_INFO (memb___id, memb__pwd, memb_name, sno__numb,bloc_code, ctl1_code,mail_chek, mail_addr,modi_days) VALUES ('test', [dbo].[fn_md5]('test','test'),'test','111','1','1','1','1','2005-03-01')

Works fine